# bash read: `vs.txt': not a valid identifier

Tags: bash, shell

I wrote a script which takes two input: first is the txt file to read, the second is a value to search in this file:

Input file 'vs.txt':

```
4ZAF:CTG trilex A-DNA:0.9:F. Haws, A. Tee, Z. Jon, M. Hams:2012-05-10
9CAA:Structure of a B-DNA dodecamer:1.9:T. Takano, C. Broka, S. Tanaka, K. Itakura:1934-08-31
7SBD:Structure analysis of the B-DNA hexamer:0.8:T. Chass:2018-09-15
5SID:Resolution crystal of A-DNA in complex:1.2:P. Drassdzal, M. Gal, R. Kisek, L. Lomdek:2009-01-03
```

my script 'structure' is:

```
#!/bin/bash
read $1 $2 -n 2
sed -e 's/,/\s/g' $1 > vstup1.txt
read -p "Zadejte desetinne cislo: " 
while IFS=":" read struktura nazev rozliseni autori rok ; do
    if [[ $struktura = $2 ]] ; then
        echo "struktura =" $struktura
        echo "nazev =" $nazev
        echo "rozliseni =" $rozliseni+$REPLY=$(awk "BEGIN {print $rozliseni+$REPLY; exit}")
        echo "autori =" $(echo "$autori" | tr -s '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]') 
        year="${rok:0:4}"; echo "rok =" "${year}"
    fi
done < vstup1.txt
```

if I run it like:

```
structure vs.txt 4ZAF
```

I see the bag:

```
./structure: line 2: read: `vs.txt': not a valid identifier
```

Even though the script is running ok on my Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: what do you think `read $1 $2 -n 2` does?

Comment: That is incorrect usage of `read` in bash. Check output of command `help read` in a bash shell.

Comment: @mjb2kmn I wouldn't call it *incorrect*, although it does rely on `$1` and `$2` expanding to valid shell identifiers.

Comment: @chepner sure `read` _could_ be used that way. I am trying to infer the author's intent and say that in this case, it is used incorrectly. They appear to be expecting it to read file contents as in `man 2 read`, which is the first man page result if you type `man read`. That is different from the bash built-in command `read` (which is why you need to check `help read`). I suspect these were confused in this case.

Comment: @EkatSim, which version of bash? For a new enough version, you can get rid of the (very inefficient and slow) `echo | tr` command substitution, and instead `echo "autori = ${autori^^}"`.

Comment: ...btw, consider generally running your code through http://shellcheck.net/ and fixing what it finds. In particular, expansions should themselves be quoted; `echo "foo = $bar"`, not `echo "foo =" $bar`.; see [BashPitfalls #14](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo) for an explanation of why `echo $foo` (with an unquoted expansion) is buggy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what your script should look like:

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Zadejte desetinne cislo: " cislo
while IFS=":" read struktura nazev rozliseni autori rok ; do
    if [[ $struktura = $2 ]] ; then
        sum=$(awk "BEGIN {print $rozliseni+$cislo; exit}")
        echo "struktura =" $struktura
        echo "nazev =" $nazev
        echo "rozliseni =" $rozliseni + $cislo "=" $sum
        echo "autori =" $(echo "$autori" | tr -s '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]')
        year="${rok:0:4}"; echo "rok =" "${year}"
    fi
done <"$1
```

I've tested with the input you've provided and it works.

Comment: Why `< <(cat $1)` instead of `<"$1"`? The former is both slower and less correct (unless `$1` is expected to string-split and glob into a list of individual files that you want to concatenate together).